# Legitimate opinions is legitimate in philosophy?

Tags: discussion

So I'm under 10 views and already received a vote to close (under opinion based). While I do agree this is well opinion based. I was under the impression having legitimate opinions was legitimate in  philosophy? But regardless I would like to know if my [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95597/dimensional-constants-evolution-and-the-anthropic-principle?noredirect=1#comment274460_95597) is legitimate under the guidelines of the site? In fact I'm sure there should be some meta where someone can redirect me to where opinion based closing on this site has been discussed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site has good standards unlike other fora where the rules are relaxed for their own reasons.

A few tips if you like SE and you should:

1. Opinion is ok, but do argue your position. If possible find legit sources that discuss and/or justify your position.
2. Include a few links on relevant concepts/ideas. Those who are serious about philosophy would like to read them.
3. Also include, to offset confirmation bias, views opposed to yours.

Others might have better advice to give.